# Python script jump the line with os and glob modules when is runned in PHP

Tags: php, python, glob

I have problem with a for cycle and glob and os modules.
In python Shell the print is printed but when i embed my python script in php it does not work.

The python below via PHP print only "first" and "second" but do not print "current file is:...".

Maybe i find another way for reading a directory?
glob and os modules are not compatible with PHP?

python:

```
print("first")
path = 'cat/tryfile'
for infile in glob.glob( os.path.join(path, '*.jpg') ):
    print("current file is: " + infile )
print("second")
```

PHP:

```
$param1 = "first";
$param2 = "second";
$param3 = "third";


$command = "C:\\python27\\python C:\\Python27\\execprova.py";


#FIRST PYTHON embedding with popen

$command .= " $param1 $param2 $param3 2>&1";
$temp = exec($command, $return);
echo "INIZIO PID";
$pid = popen( $command,"r");
echo "<body><pre>";
while( !feof( $pid ) )
{
echo fread($pid, 256);
flush();
ob_flush();

usleep(100000);
}
pclose($pid);


#SECOND PYTHON embedding with exec          
echo (" {PHP inizio command output return ed exec  /PHP} ");

$command = "C:\\python27\\python C:\\Python27\\bp1imgsenzaprint.py";
$output = null;
$temp = exec($command);


function success() 
{
$mystring = exec('C:\\python27\\python C:\\Python27\\bp1imgsenzaprint.py', $output);
var_dump($output);
var_dump($mystring);
print_r($output);
}

print("SUCCESS");
success();
```

Comment: Use absolute path in your Python script's `path` variable instead of relative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always take care when using relative paths in CLI scripts. The working directory and `PATH` environment variable are often not what you'd normally expect.

In Python, you can set the [working directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) (similarly to Windows/*nix's [`cd` command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_%28command%29)) with [`os.chdir(path)`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.html) so that you can safely use relative paths, or use absolute paths instead by either hardcoding or concatenating the containing directory path with the relative file path.

Comment: I mentioned the `PATH` mainly for personal experience: Python 2.7 under Windows' `subprocess.Popen()` without `shell=True` parameter will not run with the system's `PATH`; shell scripts running through Ubuntu's crontabs also do not use the user's `PATH` without some hackarounds/importing. So, if relative paths are not the problem, you should next check the value of the `PATH` variable inside the given script.